# How to sort based on one column while clicking on the header of another column in asp.net 2.0 gridview?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using .Net2.0.
I have the following code in my Custom GridView:

```
<cc1:MyGrid  ID="myGrid" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" OnSortCommand="MyGrid_SortCommand"
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="col1" SortExpression="col1" HeaderText="col1"
                            DataFormatString="{0}" Visible="False">

                        </asp:BoundColumn>
                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="col2" SortExpression="col1" HeaderText="col2"
                            DataFormatString="{0}">

                        </asp:BoundColumn>

  </Columns>
                </cc1:MyGrid>
```

Basically my intention is when I am clicking on the column header of col2,it should sort by col1;hence the SortExpression of col2 is col1.
But in my MyGrid_SortCommand event:

```
protected void MyGrid_SortCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
      {
Response.Write(e.SortExpression);
}
```

Here the e.SortExpression is always coming as col2 whenever I am clicking on col2 instead of col1.
Any clue why the sort expression is not changing despite changing in aspx file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a type <asp:BoundColumn DataField="col2" **SortExpression="col1"** it seems the SortExpression for col2 is still col1?

Comment: I want sort expression for col2 to be col1, but in runtime it still remains col2 only.

Comment: I think there is something very simple I m missing,just could not figure it out!

Comment: can you post your userControl grid?

Comment: It's something like this:public class myGrid : DataGrid, ILocalizableControl
 { public myGrid()
            : base()
  {
  }  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "table-grid");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);            
            base.CssClass = "display dataTable no-footer";
            base.ItemStyle.CssClass = "dt-body-center";           
            base.Render(writer);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }}